# While trying to access Talend v5.6.1 getting an error

Tags: talend

While I am trying to access Talend v5.6.1 64 bit getting an error as beloved in screen shot.

Quick reply can be helpful for me.

Error image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have Java 8 on your computer, but version 5.6.1 of Talend only supports Java 7. So you need to either install Java 7 or download a later version of Talend (like 6.4.1) which supports Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply will try as you said